# What is the female equivalent of a 'monk'?

Tags: meaning

I don't exactly know what the author of this task had in mind, but I am supposed to fill in female equivalents for different words and I stumbled across this. The only idea I have is a "nun" but I am not sure whether it is the same.

Comment: Yes, I would say "nun".

Comment: Look up nun in a dictionary and come back to us if you still have difficulty.

Comment: Thanks everyone for help! Glad I got my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the following [extract](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monk#:%7E:text=The%20word%20nun%20is%20typically,other%20religious%20or%20philosophical%20backgrounds.), the term “nun” is used for female monastics, but there are exceptions:

> In the Greek language the term (monk) can apply to women, but in modern English it is mainly in use for men. ***The word nun is typically used for female monastics.***
>
> Although the term monachos is of Christian origin, in the English language monk tends to be used loosely also for both male and female ascetics from other religious or philosophical backgrounds. However, being generic, it is not interchangeable with terms that denote particular kinds of monk, such as cenobite, hermit, anchorite, hesychast, or solitary.

(Wikipedia)

Comment: I am tremendously grateful for your help , thank you!

Comment: Was this question really suitable for this site? I usually err on the tolerant side but this is really too trivial to be anywhere but English Language Lesrners.

Comment: But not Anton's downvote. ELU is aimed at linguists.

Comment: It was not my downvote, but - amusingly - it is my miss-spelling in my previous comment. The biter bit? I have clarified the Wikipedia quote to make sense.